# Do we have to put in empty arguments "void" or not?

Tags: c

Recently I read the "K&R" book, where it is written that, if we don't have arguments in our function, we have to write "void" in brackets to make the program work correctly, with old standards too. Do we need it these days?

Example:

```
int foo(void)
{
/*...*/
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the ***declaration*** of your function (rather than calling it - see below), then the following (from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_declaration)), should answer your question:

> The declarators `f()` and `f(void)` have different meaning: the declarator
>   `f(void)` is a **new-style** (prototype) declarator that declares a function
>   that takes no parameters. The declarator `f()` is an **old-style** (K&R)
>   declarator that declares a function that takes an ***unspecified number of
>   parameters*** (unless used in an old-style function definition)

However, when calling a function, you ***cannot*** include the `void` keyword: `int p = func(void);` won't compile - you have to use `int p = func();`.